# VBA: ошибка Module not found (Access, Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, utf-8, access, office

Хочу поделиться решением. После установки Office 2021 и открытия заведомо рабочей базы Access сыпятся ошибки вида "Выражение Текущая запись, введенное в поле свойства события, вызывает ошибку Module not found"

[image: Access Module not found]

Если открываю VBA (даже в Excel) код не грузится, кириллицу выводит кракозябрами, зачастую Office совсем вылетает.

[image: VBA error module not found]

Гуглил по запросам "microsoft access module not found, "vba cyrillic utf8", не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось простым: раньше я по глупости поставил галочку "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире" в региональных настройках. Убрал, перезагрузил систему и все решилось